# Date difference (UNIX)

Tags: javascript

I need to find the seconds long my token (jwt) is.
Normally my token returns 2 properties that indicate the creation and the expiration date:

```
"iat": 1622583091
"exp": 1622584891
```

Now I need to find the difference in seconds between those two dates.
The first thing I did is convert those dates to a readable format:

```
const iat = new Date (1622583091 * 1000); /* Tue Jun 01 2021 15:40:16 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) */
const iat = new Date (1622584891 * 1000); /* Tue Jun 01 2021 16:10:16 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) */
```

Worse now I can't think of how I can evaluate those dates and get the seconds of difference.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Of course it does. If you have the number of minutes, multiply by 60 to get the number of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way so simple, you just have to subtract the times iat and exp. This will return an integer:

```js
const iat = 1622583091;
const exp = 1622584891;

let result = iat - exp;
console.log(Math.abs(result));
```

And here I already have my difference in seconds